# Converting a DateTime string in Rails with to_time to_datetime acts different. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, to-date

After deploying my rails app to a VPS I had some problems with 'time'.  After some puzzling I found out that Rails is acting in a strange way when using the date/time conversion.

My server is set to **timezone "Amsterdam"** and in the Rails config I also have set timezome to "Amsterdam"

#### example:

I receive this string via my body content in a json/api

`date = "13-03-2015 09:29"`

when I convert this string like this:
`date.to_datetime`, the result is *"Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:29:00 +0000"*

when I convert the string like this:
`date.to_time`, the result is *"2015-03-13 09:29:00 +0100"*

As you can see there is a difference in the way it is adding the time correction *"+0000"* vs *"+0100"*

So when I convert like this:
`date.to_time.to_datetime`, the result is *"Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:29:00 +0100"*

And this is the result I needed, because my postgres database otherwise gave me back a wrong date (+1 hour)

#### My questions are:

1. What is the explanation for the difference in behaviour of `.to_date and` and  `.to_datetime`
2. How does Postgres handle dates. When saving a datetime parameter like this *"Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:29:00 +0000"* and I render this date in a json response it is 1 hour later.

Hope someone can explain this to me.
Martijn

Comment: `date.to_datetime` directly returns the date and `date.to_time.to_datetime` method internally convert date to `UTC` format  `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`

Comment: And when you save the date in Postgres it save it as `2015-03-13 09:29:00  UTC+5:30` and when you retrieve it it gives you GMT time `2015-03-13 14:59:00`, both the dates are same `2015-03-13 09:29:00  UTC+5:30` = `2015-03-13 14:59:00`